# How to decrypt file via C# using PGPTool keys

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, pgp, openpgp

I have private and public keys that was created in [PGPTool](https://pgptool.github.io/) and I need to decrypt file using C# with private key and password, but every PGP library that I was using throw exception.

Library that I was try in my code: PGPCore, OpenPGP, ChoPGP.
All this library using bouncycastle lib in background.

Exception throw on this lin
`PgpObjectFactory objFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream));`

{"Secret key for message not found."}

I want to find solution for decrypt file using keys from PGPTool.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?  I have been sitting here fighting with the same issue no matter what library I use.  Oddly enough, I was able to encrypt/decrypt messages using the keys generated with PGPTool using the online wp2pgpmail tool.